# How the elements of a matrix and its inverse are related

Tags: matrices, limits, inverse

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be a invertible symmetric positive definite matrix, $a_{ij}>0\,\,\forall i,j$, let $B=A^{-1}=(b_{ij})$. How do I prove, if it is really true, whether $a_{ij}\approx 0\Leftrightarrow\,\,b_{ij}\approx\infty$. Or alternatively, $a_{ij}\to 0\Leftrightarrow\,\,b_{ij}\to\infty$. Or, if the proposition is not true in general, in which cases (assumptions) would it be true?

[additional comment:]

It seems in general that is not true, but in which conditions that would be true, that is, which assumptions should we add to the problem in order to make the proposition true? Let me be a bit more specific. The matrix A is of the form
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
A_{11} & A_{12}\\
A_{21} & A_{22}
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $A_{11}^{p\times p}$, $A_{12}^{p\times k}$, $A_{21}^{k\times p}=A_{12}^T$, $A_{22}^{k\times k}$, both $A_{11}$ and $A_{22}$ are invertible, symmetric, all the entries of A are positive. The entries of $A_{12}$, $A_{21}$ and $A_{22}$ tend to infinity. So, what happens to the entries of $A^{-1}$? Could we state at least that some of the entries tend to zero?

Comment: Probably by looking at the determinant. If det($A$) is very small then det($A^{-1}$) must be large. Thus $A^{-1}$ must have large terms.

Comment: Do know any reference of how to prove it? Thanks

Comment: Look up Cramer’s formula for inversion.

Comment: This is not true for identity matrix.

Comment: True, I have edited it to exclude the identify matrix of the proposition. thanks

Comment: I can't follow this... you wrote $A$ is invertible spd, but then say $a_{ij}>0\,\,\forall i,j$ which is unrelated to being positive definite, and then say $A\neq I$ which is not needed if each component is positive.  In general what you want to prove is not true.

Comment: This is too simple and wrong. You can consider the $b_{ij}$ as polynomials in the variables $a_{ij}$. Here is the formula: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#In_relation_to_its_adjugate

Comment: user8675309, I have rephrased it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My feeling is that in general it is not true because the limit of many variables is not uniquely defined. In the case you multiply every $a_{ij}>0$ by the same number $t$,then you calculate the inverse and then let $t \rightarrow 0$, then it is true that every $b_{ij}$ will diverge as $1/t$, if not zero in the first place.

EDIT: I add an example, just to show what can happen for a generic parametrization $a_{ij} = a_{ij}(t)$, such that $a_{ij}(t) \rightarrow 0$ when $t \rightarrow 0$. Consider a simple $2\times 2$ case,

$$
a_{11}= t^2 \quad a_{12}=a_{21}= t  \quad a_{22}= t^4  \, .
$$

The inverse is (in the limit $t \rightarrow 0^+$)

$$
b_{11}= 0 \quad b_{12}=  b_{21}= \infty   \quad b_{22}= -1
$$

You have the whole spectrum: something is zero, something diverges, something is finite and negative.

Comment: I have added some comments in the original post.

Comment: Still you have to define HOW you want the $a_{ij}$ to go to zero. There is no concept as the "limit of many variables". You have to define a parametrization $a_{ij}(t)$ in terms of a single variable $t$. This is the point of my answer. I supposed $a_{ij}(t) = t a_{ij}$. If this is the case, my answer remains true even with the new edit.

Comment: Maybe I can show you an example, I will add it to my answer.

Comment: $a_{ij}=exp(c t^2)$ c: some constant, if that is of any help. Maybe we could do some algebra, separating the sub-matrices, those tending to infinity and $A_{11}$ (which is fixed). I will try to think over.

Comment: @Ludwig you cannot change the problem or adding a bit of new (relevant) information on it every time. I consider my answer as "definitive", according to the the original problem you posted. Please remember also to upvote the comments or answers that you found interesting or gave you useful hints. I see many people that gave you valuable hints.